# padding-top to h1 in vertically align div

Tags: css

i have a  div that has a specific height and the content inside adjusts according to height VERTICALLY now what i did is i added the property `display-table;` to the parent div and `display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;` to the child div  now what happens is my div is vertically aligned and looking good but the h1 inside the child i not exactly as centered aligned as the button i figured adding some padding top or margin top might solve the issue but it is not accepting either of these here's my code

html

```
<div class="all-smiles" id="parent">
    <div id="child">
    <div class="container" align="center">
        <div class="row">
                <h1>All Smiles Welcome</h1>
                <button>BOOK AN APPOINTMENT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#parent {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}
.all-smiles {
    background-color: #b7181c;
}
.all-smiles h1 {
    color: white;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
.all-smiles button {
    padding: 12px;
    background: 0;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: young;
}

#child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/25wf6oey/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify these two:

- Vertical Alignment as `middle`
- Line height and `1`

Code:

```
.all-smiles h1 {
  color: white;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 3%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wd3sr2xv/**